# storing result of MySQL query into python variable

Tags: python, mysql

when I execute the following code using python programming language and MySQL database

```
cursor.execute("select max(propernoun_SRNO) from tblauto_tagged")
starting_index = cursor.fetchone()
ending_index = starting_index +len(s)
```

---

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
batch(1,1)
File "C:\Users\vchauhan\Dropbox\Code\proper_noun_function_batch_file_mysql_sept_12.py", line 97, in batch
ending_index = starting_index +len(s)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pyodbc.Row' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

The problem here is that you are assigning `pyodbc.Row` instance (returned by `.fetchone()`) to `starting_index`, which makes it impossible to add it to the integer (thus the "*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)*" error).

### Solution

Try to replace this line:

```
starting_index = cursor.fetchone()
```

with this line:

```
starting_index = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

### More reading

- [PEP 249 - Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (especially part about `fetchone()`)